# AWS SDK C++ install using cmake on Ubuntu, problem with installing third-party libraries

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cmake, aws-sdk

I am installing the `aws-cpp-sdk` in Ubuntu 20.04 by following the installation instructions on: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp

I built/installed the SDK from source as per the instructions which worked. Installation locations:

- /usr/local/lib
- /usr/local/include/aws

I built/installed the `aws-c-common` as per the instructions (although I didn't use a `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`).

I attempt to build `aws-checksums` but can't get past the cmake. When I run `cmake ..` while in the build directory which is in the code directory I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
/usr/local/lib/cmake/lib/cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsCFlags

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsCheckHeaders

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsSharedLibSetup

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsSanitizers

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsFindPackage

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AwsFeatureTests

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:116 (aws_set_common_properties):
  Unknown CMake command "aws_set_common_properties".

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also ...
```

I've tried to point the prefix to the sdk install folders but that did not solve my problem. That is where I get stuck. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you have added some `message()` call to [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-checksums/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt), and this call prints the line `/usr/local/lib/cmake/lib/cmake`. This is value of `AWS_MODULE_PATH` variable, isn't it? Their computations of the variable are quite strange.
It seems the value of the variable should be `/usr/local/lib/cmake`. Try to set the variable directly in `CMakeLists.txt` to that value (and check whether this directory contains `AwsCFlags.cmake` and other `.cmake` scripts).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the hint. You're right, I had to change the prefix. `cmake ..  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/` although some tests do fail. I you want to write an answer go for it, otherwise should I delete this post?

Comment: I don't want to answer. I can see only into their `CMakeLists.txt`, and from my understanding calculations of `AWS_MODULE_PATH` is a problem. But I don't know the **correct** way. You may answer your question and describe the **working** way. (While we prefer "working" to be same as "correct", but in the real life they could differ sometimes:))

Answer (score 4):

If you are building from source make sure to use this command

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp
```

I ran into a similar issue while building because I was missing the **--recurse-submodules** tag. I built inside a docker container running Ubuntu. My solution is for the AWS cpp sdk, but it might also work for your case.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. Turns out they've started to use submodules somewhere in between 1.7.x and 1.9.x, thus our scripts were broken.

Answer (score 2):

I do this inside a Dockerfile, and it runs properly:

```
RUN cd /tmp \
  && git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git \
  && cd aws-sdk-cpp \
  && mkdir build \
  && cd build \
  && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_ONLY="ecr" \
  && make \
  && make install
```

It builds without the -DBUILD_ONLY option as well. However, this is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, not 20.04. I don't imagine there's a difference, however.

You haven't said what options you're feeding cmake.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for commenting. I agree that is builds your way but not fully. As I mentioned, I did a basic setup as per the ReadMe which means I didn't set anything during the install of the sdk. In order for me to run the basic s3-sample, I need to install the third-party dependencies outlined in the readme of the sdk. They don't seem to fully install even tough the aws-sdk-cpp Cmakelist is.txt indicates an option BUILD_DEPS ON by default. Maybe I'm missing a setting. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: When cloning you need to --recurse-submodules otherwise cmake configure will not work (and consequently build).

Comment: @tothphu I don't think that was originally necessary, but it is now. I updated my answer.

Comment: --recurse-submodules  did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I've created a demo application [s3-demo](https://github.com/unfor19/docker-aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/src/s3-demo.cpp) that gets the list of buckets in a specific region. This project is available at [github.com/unfor19/docker-aws-sdk-cpp](https://github.com/unfor19/docker-aws-sdk-cpp)

I also had the same issue that you had (and many more), but I was finally able to cook a Dockerfile that builds aws-sdk-cpp and the demo application.

Here's my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/unfor19/docker-aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
ARG AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION="1.8.160"
ARG AWS_SDK_CPP_BUILD_TYPE="Release"
ARG APP_BUILD_TYPE="Release"

### -----------------------------------------------------
### Base image
### -----------------------------------------------------
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base

# Fix tzdata hang
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    curl wget git zip unzip \
    cmake g++ gcc \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libpulse-dev \
    uuid-dev zlib1g-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    make golang-1.13

ENV PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/go-1.13/bin"
COPY scripts/ /usr/local/bin/
WORKDIR /code/


### -----------------------------------------------------
### Build aws-sdk-cpp
### -----------------------------------------------------
FROM base as build-aws-sdk-cpp
ARG AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION
ARG AWS_SDK_CPP_BUILD_TYPE
ENV AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION="${AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION}" \
    AWS_SDK_CPP_BUILD_TYPE="${AWS_SDK_CPP_BUILD_TYPE}"
WORKDIR /code/
RUN download.sh "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/archive/${AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION}.zip"
WORKDIR /sdk_build/
RUN cmake /code/aws-sdk-cpp-${AWS_SDK_CPP_VERSION} -DBUILD_ONLY="s3" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="${AWS_SDK_CPP_BUILD_TYPE}"
RUN make && \
    make install && \
    rm -rf /code/


### -----------------------------------------------------
### Build the application
### -----------------------------------------------------
FROM build-aws-sdk-cpp as build-app
WORKDIR /code/
COPY . .
ARG APP_BUILD_TYPE
ENV APP_BUILD_TYPE="${APP_BUILD_TYPE}"
RUN rm -rf build && cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="${APP_BUILD_TYPE}"
WORKDIR /code/build/
RUN make
# Default region N.Virginia
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, When I downloaded the zip bundle. Later I used git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp to get the source code. That worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).